# C++ Visual Studio 19 / OpenCV - Video Codex: Guide how to install mpeg4 library / header files needed

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2019, codec, mpeg

In principal I am capable to install 3rd party libraries to my **VS 2019 Projects**, at least have done it on several occasions in the past.
**Unfortunatley I struggle to do so on the mpeg4 codex** (also on others...).
I followed a few instructions, downloaded and added all .lib(s) and headers, but still fail with LINK2019 erros when compiling.
**A short and simple guide would be highly appreciated.**
If any other codex is easier, fine by me... (failed also on avi codecs :( )
Thanks in advance, T
#######################

Note: opencv4 fully installed with vcpkg and linked (all other cv2 features working)

**Details to the error:**
as soon as I add following line:

VideoWriter video(videofile, cv::VideoWriter::fourcc('M', 'J', 'P', 'G'), CamFPS, Size(CamY, CamX));

Following error:

LNK2019 unresolved external symbol "public: **thiscall cv::VideoWriter::VideoWriter(class cv::String const &,int,double,class cv::Size*,bool)" (??0VideoWriter@cv@@QAE@ABVString@1@HNV?$Size*@H@1@_N@Z) referenced in function _main   xx  C:\Users\xxx\source\repos\xx\xx\Source1.obj 1

**What could be the problem?**

Comment: You probably want to use vcpkg to build opencv. [https://vcpkg.info/port/opencv](https://vcpkg.info/port/opencv)

Comment: Interestingly, I have done so initially. I normally only transfered into the project directory the relevant headers and libs. There are imgcodecs / video headers and library, but I may assumed I may need an additional library for mpeg4. Just made a new project and pointed to the vcpkg/packages/opencv directory and still get an compile error - in this case: "cannot open file 'C:\vcpkg\packages\opencv4_x86-windows\lib.obj" ... there is no obj.lib file, what could be the problem? Thanks

Comment: You probably used an improper dependency. You probably meant to add `C:\vcpkg\packages\opencv4_x86-windows\lib` as a library folder to search when looking for libraries but instead added it as file dependency.

Comment: I corrected the path as per your suggestion and it fails now again on the error:" ..//vcpkg//packages//opencv4_x86-windows//lib.obj" cannot open file...  Reinstalled opencv via vcpkg again, relinked it to a new VS projekt, but still the same problem :( ... any other ideas?

Comment: That is the same error and same problem. I don't know where you are typing this in but its the wrong place.

Comment: Yes, shame on me! You were right, I had incorrectly a link to the libs in "Linker - Input - Additional Dependencies" - thanks for your help!

Comment: `Linker->General->Additional Library Directories` is the location to put folders for the linker to search for libraries you put in the `Linker -> Input -> Additional Dependencies` setting.